# ToString() in variable/ Expression window in FlashBuilder

Tags: actionscript-3, ide, flash-builder

Is there a way to display something else then the classe name in variable/ Expression window in FlashBuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you'll find all local variables with their current value (when stopped at a specific break point) in the "Variables" tab.

If you want to inspect other values or some specific expressions, you can switch to the "Expressions" tab, click "Add new expression", type your own variables/expressions and press enter to see the current value.

Of course doing so has the following limitations:

- Namespaces are not supported.
- Inline objects are not supported.
- The keyword super is not supported.
- Most E4X expressions can be evaluated, but E4X filter expressions are not supported.
  For example, you cannot evaluate myxml.(@id=='3')).
- You cannot call functions that are defined as a variable.
- Fully qualified class names are not supported.
  For example, you cannot evaluate mx.controls.Button.
  You can refer to the unqualified class name. For example, you can specify Button to refer to mx.controls.Button.
  If a class name is ambiguous (two classes with the same name in different packages,) then you cannot control which class will be evaluated. However, you can specify:

  getDefinitionByName("mx.controls.Button")

[(Source)](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.6/UsingFlashBuilder/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-14e0a01012e4c877c1d-8000.html)